# How to delete mySQL records that are empty?

Tags: mysql

Hello I have thousands of record like these and my question is how do I delete them using sql query?

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing, search for "SQL DELETE" - then try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `meta_key` is `null` you can use

```
delete from your_table
where meta_key is null
```

If it is just an empty string use

```
delete from your_table
where meta_key = ''
```

and if your `meta_key` contains just spaces then use (which could run slower)

```
delete from your_table
where trim(meta_key) = ''
```

Comment: i tried it nut it does not work

Comment: 0 rows deleted. ( Query took 0.6698 sec )

Comment: try again with `where meta_key = ''`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`meta_key`) < 1
```